# Using a Wrapper Type for a DTO in Spring + Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to find a more or less elegant way to handle PATCH http operations in Spring MVC.

Basically, I'd like to perform a "dual" Jackson deserialization of a JSON document from a Request Body: one to a Map, and the other to the target POJO. Ideally, I would like to perform this in a single `PartialDto<T>` instance, where T is my target DTO type.

Better giving an example. Let's say I currently have this PUT mapping in a REST Controller:

```java
    @PutMapping("/resource")
    public MyDto updateWhole(@RequestBody MyDto dto) {
        System.out.println("PUT: updating the whole object to " + dto);
        return dto;
    }
```

My idea is to build a `PartialDto` type that would provide both POJO representation of the request body, as well as the Map representation, like this:

```java
    @PatchMapping("/resource")
    public MyDto updatePartial(@RequestBody PartialDto<MyDto> partial) {
        System.out.println("PATCH: partial update of the object to " + partial);

        final MyDto dto = partial.asDto();
        // Do stuff using the deserialized POJO

        final Map<String, Object> map = partial.asMap();
        // Do stuff as a deserialized map...

        return dto;
    }
```

I hope this will allow me to further expand the PartialDto implementation so I can perform things like this:

```java
        if (partial.hasAttribute("myAttribute")) {
            final String myAttribute = dto.getMyAttribute();
            // ...
        }
```

Or even using a metamodel generator:

```java
        if (partial.hasAttribute(MyDto_.myAttribute)) {
            final String myAttribute = dto.getMyAttribute();
            // ...
        }
```

So the **question** is simple: Jackson can easily map a JSON document to a POJO. It can also easily map a JSON document to a java Map. How can I do both at the same time in a Wrapper object such as my PartialDto?

```java
public class PartialDto<T> {
    private final Map<String, Object> map;
    private final T dto;

    PartialDto(Map<String, Object> map, T dto) {
        this.map = map;
        this.dto = dto;
    }

    public T asDto() {
        return this.dto;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> asMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.map);
    }
}
```

I tried to use a GenericConverter like this (that, of course, I registered in Spring MVC's FormatterRegistry):

```java
public class PartialDtoConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public PartialDtoConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(new ConvertiblePair(String.class, PartialDto.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        final Class<?> targetClazz = targetType.getResolvableType().getGeneric(0).getRawClass();
        final Map<String, Object> map;
        try {
            map = objectMapper.readValue((String) source, Map.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // FIXME
        }
        final Object dto = objectMapper.convertValue(map, targetClazz);
        return new PartialDto(map, dto) ;
    }
}
```

And this converter works well when tested directly using Spring's ConversionService:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ConverterTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Test
    public void testPartialUpdate() throws Exception {
        final MyDto dto = new MyDto()
                .setIt("It");

        final PartialDto<MyDto> partialDto = (PartialDto<MyDto>) conversionService.convert(
                "{ \"it\": \"Plop\" }",
                new TypeDescriptor(ResolvableType.forClass(String.class), null, null),
                new TypeDescriptor(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(PartialDto.class, MyDto.class), null, null)
        );

        Assertions.assertEquals("Plop", partialDto.asDto().getIt());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Plop", partialDto.asMap().get("it"));
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work in a @RequestBody such as shown above. Reminder:

```java
    @PatchMapping("/resource")
    public MyDto updatePartial(@RequestBody PartialDto<MyDto> partial) {
        // ...
    }
```

Any idea is welcome.